# Are post-hoc adjusted analyses more valid than initial analyses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, group-differences, clinical-trials

Many papers design a methodology to detect a difference between $2$ groups regarding a primary outcome. This result is then given a $p$ value to denote statistical significance. Some papers then go on to adjust their analysis for age, sex, weight, height etc., and report a statistically non-significant difference between the $2$ groups for the same primary outcome.

Does the statistically non-significant value from the post-hoc adjusted analysis supersede the initial analysis of the primary outcome which isn't adjusted for confounders?

Comment: Deciding to control or adjust for these factors is better done before collecting or analysing the data.

Comment: The difference between "significant" and "not significant" is not itself statistically significant http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf

Answer (score 7):

> Does the statistically insignificant value from the post-hoc adjusted analysis supercede the initial analysis of the primary outcome which isn't adjusted for confounders?

What I assume you're trying to ask is "which outcome do I believe?  Should I believe that there is a difference between groups larger than what sampling variation could explain under the null?".  The answer is "it depends on what is being conditioned on".

If:

- Adjustment factors satisfy the back door criterion under your causal model, and/or
- The exposure is independent of adjustment factors, but adjustment factors are possible causes of the outcome

then the adjusted analyses is likely a better analyses.  Adjusting for confounders will remove any confounding in the estimate, and adjusting for covariates which are unrelated to the exposure but causes of the outcome can reduce variance in the estimate.

You have to be careful here though, because careless adjustment can open backdoors and *introduce bias* by conditioning on a collider in the causal diagram.  This is why I say "it depends".

Consider an extreme cases where the unadjusted estimate might be preferable to the adjusted estimate.  A randomized experiment is run, but the investigators condition on a collider thereby introducing a spurious correlation between exposure and outcome.

In general, adjustment should be preferred to unadjusted but only if the adjustment makes sense.  Else, you get what Richard McElrath calls ["causal salad"](https://go-bayes.github.io/rbb-causal/#:%7E:text=Causal%20salad%20means%20tossing%20various,can%20mislead%20us%20about%20causation.).

Answer (score 3):

I think Demetri's answer hits the nail on the head, but I would like to add that how this is accomplished is also very important. If the scientists pre-specified that there would be differences between groups, but then post-hoc explain their results in terms of other confounders/colliders, then there need to be one of two conditions met:

- **If they hypothesized this in advance, they need to state this explicitly**. This is really the only way this sort of analysis can be considered confirmatory, as they are not jumping on chance findings after rummaging through the data.
- **If they did not hypothesize this in advance, they need to state that this was an exploratory finding**. There is nothing wrong with this and should honestly be more commonplace anyway (see Tong, 2019 for a useful discussion on how most science is actually exploratory anyway).

##### Reference

Tong, C. (2019). Statistical inference enables bad science; statistical thinking enables good science. The American Statistician, 73(sup1), 246–261. https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2018.1518264

Comment: Good points ! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The results of the new model will override any prior results where we did not control for confounders or other relevant predictors.  Each variable will explain some portion of the variance in the outcome.  However these variances will often overlap. The effect of one variable may be better explained by the effect of another variable.  I've seen this occur very frequently in studies looking at health or race.  When we do not account for these confounding variables, we will often get type 2 errors.